# Using dictionary as D3 data source

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to use this data (below) as a data source for a d3.js program:

```
{
  "component": {
    "name1": {
      "graphname": {
        "title": "foo",
        "data": [
          {"data": "DATE IN ISOFORMAT", "value": 5},
          {"data": "DATE IN ISOFORMAT", "value": 10}
          ]
      }
    },
    "name2": {
      "graphname": {
        "title": "foo",
        "data": [
          {"data": "DATE IN ISOFORMAT", "value": 5},
          {"data": "DATE IN ISOFORMAT", "value": 10}
          ]
      }
    }
  }
  "component2": {...
}
```

D3 accepts only array data? How i can manipulate it to work?

I want to graph for all component any "graphname" aggregated by "name"

Any tips?

Answer (score 4):

D3 does *not* just accept arrays as data sources, but for looping purposes, arrays are much more convenient than JavaScript objects ("dicts"). There is a very easy way to convert objects to arrays, though. If your object above were called `d`, then its corresponding array can be created with:

```
var dlist = d3.entries(d);
```

Now `dlist` will be something like:

```
[ { key: 'component',
    value: { name1: ..., name2: ... } },
  { key: 'component2',
    value: { name1: ..., name2: ... } } ]
```

The original dict has been remapped into an array of "records," each with `key` and `value` pairs. This "array of records" pattern is very common in D3 work, and JavaScript in general. If you need to loop over the sub-structures (e.g. the `name1`, `name2`, ... values, `d3.entries` can be applied at multiple levels of the original structure, as those dict-to-list transforms are required.

Since this answer is called out in the comments as wrong, [here's a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/t23v5h7L/1/) of using an object ("dict") as a data source for a D3 program: first in a simple loop, then secondarily using the idiomatic d3 `.data(...).enter()` pipeline.

Comment: Your answer is wrong: In D3, `data()` accepts **only** 3 things: an array, a function or nothing. It does **not** accept an object. As "nothing" is used only when `data()` is a getter and a function ultimately refers to an array, you can indeed say that the only data structure D3 accepts is an array.

Comment: My answer is correct. The `selection.data()` method may work with only arrays (or functions that produce same), probably because arrays have been the only easily iterable structures in JavaScript. But D3 **programs** accept and use data in any shape, form, or format. The trick is to use transforms, like the `d3.entries()` I detailed, to move from the input data to one that individual D3 methods can easily consume. Btw, D3 programs often use `.data()` (and that is the idiom), but it is not essential. Many D3 programs don't use that particular method.

Comment: Show me just one.

Comment: It looks like it works like Object.values(). Is that correct  Jonathan?

Comment: @rasmeister It works more like the "experimental" [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Browser_compatibility) which is not standardized or commonly available. So libraries like d3.js and underscore.js add their own versions.

Comment: I believe you know that `d3.entries(d)` returns an **array**. Besides that, using a `forEach` is plain javascript, you don't even need D3 for that. As any D3 coder, I was talking about *data binding*. However, since you treated me like an imbecile in your code ("amazing", astoundingly"), I have nothing more to tell you.

Comment: So the "Your answer is wrong" and a downvote of a correct answer are...respectful? You asked for a counterexample; I provided. It is, in fact, surprising that d3 doesn't need the data pipeline for which it's so well known. Sure that one `.data` needs an array; but `d3.entries` yields such one. Problem solved.

Comment: @Kaylas Please consider up-voting answers that were helpful to you, and/or marking one of them as "the preferred answer" (by clicking the checkmark at the top left of the answer).